# Use typescript to restrict string literal type

Tags: typescript, naming-conventions, typescript-template-literals

I would like to use typescript to enforce a "t-shirt" naming convention.

Can I for example create a typescript type `TShirt` which would work something like the following:

```js
const name: TShirt = 'xs' // ok
const name: TShirt = 'xxxxxxxxxxs' // ok
const name: TShirt = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxl' // ok
const name: TShirt = 'xsz' // gives error
```

There are an infinite number of allowed types:

```
... xxxs, xxs, xs, s, m, l, xl, xxl, xxxl ...
```

Comment: Am I missing something or this should be a union ?

Comment: ...however, "an infinite number of allowed types" is not viable. You'll need to choose a sensible cutoff point.

Comment: You could use integers where ..., -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... corresponds to ..., xxxs, xxs, xs, s, m, l, xl, xxl, xxxl, ...